# How to calculate thermal load?

Tags: heat-transfer, heating-systems

basically I am trying to build an oven that we are going to use to cure prepreg carbon fiber. I found a company that can make it but they are requesting the termal load in order to continue.

This is the information I already have:
Dimensions of the oven: 23.7in x 59in x 59in (height, width, depth)
Desired temperatures: max 284F, min 158F

I have found the formula to calculate this, but honestly, I don't know how to begin:

```
q = -k A dt/dx
q = heat transfer rate, Btu/hr
k = thermal conductivity, Btu/(hr-ft-F)
A = area normal to heat flow, ft^2
dt/dx = temperature gradient, F/ft
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd tell them what you're aiming to do e.g. the required temperature range, heat up time, is it open or closed, is there material moving through it continually or is it a batch process, what is the ambient temperature, etc.

They should do the thermal load calculations and guarantee the performance. If they can't, you should probably look for another supplier.  Otherwise, if it doesn't work they're going to tell you that you gave them the wrong thermal load.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for heat transfer is not of much value here.

You literally need the heat to cure the prepreg carbon fiber.  At 284F how much heat is the absorbed.

I need an engine to go 60 mph.  A motorcycle would need a different hp than a truck.